# I want to get a data from the array if it is stored in the mysql , it store a lat and lng

Tags: mysql, angular

I want to get lat and long value separately from the database in laravel5.

```
$vehiclelocation=Vehicle::select('veh_last_location')->get()->toArray();
dd($vehiclelocation[0]['veh_last_location']);
```

Getting a response in such a way:-

```
"[{"lati":18.5204303,"long":73.85674369999992}]"
```

I want lat as a different parameter and long as different parameter. Is it possible through a JSON decode?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `JSON.parse`:

```js
var response = '[{"lati":18.5204303,"long":73.85674369999992}]';
var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(parsedResponse[0].lati);
console.log(parsedResponse[0].long);
```

Or if you have exactly specified string (with leading and trailing quotes), you should slice them before parsing:

```js
var response = '"[{"lati":18.5204303,"long":73.85674369999992}]"';
var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response.slice(1, -1));
console.log(parsedResponse[0].lati);
console.log(parsedResponse[0].long);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```js
var data = [{"lati":18.5204303,"long":73.85674369999992}]

var expectedData = {
  lat: data[0].lati,
  long: data[0].long
}
console.log(expectedData);
```